# Why is cycles rendering blurry Boolean detail

Tags: cycles-render-engine

[image]Would really appreciate some help figuring why the detail in this render is all blurry?The mesh was an imported svg, converted to mesh, cleaned up and the difference and mirror modifier applied.Thanks
[blend file here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/i1qzr3asq1ch2ov/unleashrenderstack.blend?dl=0)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @Jackdaw,turns out it was a bevel modifier in the stack. Took it out and it was good to. Lesson of the day... Always check ya stack

Answer (score 0):

It seems like Cycles have a hard time figuring out how to deal with the N-Gons here. Try add a Triangulate modifier and change methods if needed.